# Scanf with string format

Tags: c

I made a code that supposed to take stdin and make sure it is true depending on my scanf format.

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    char* a;
    i = 0;
    while (1 == scanf("/%[^/ \t\n]", a[i++]))
         printf(">%s<\n", a[i-1]);

    return 0;
}
```

sample input:

```
/test
```

sample output:

```
/test
Segmentation fault
```

I have no idea what is causing the segmentation fault

Comment: `char str[32];
    char* a = str;
    i = 0;
    while (1 == scanf("/%[^/ \t\n]", a))
         printf(">%s<\n", a);`

Comment: A good start would be to use the debugger to find out where exactly the crash occured.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY the a has to be how it was, thats a requirement.

Comment: @Olaf I tried debugging but it led me to nothing useful or traceable.

Comment: The pointer must point to the reserved area. and type of `a[index]` is `char`, not `char*`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY i tried making `char a[32]` and leaving the `a` inside `scanf` and `printf` the same but its not printing out `>test<`

Comment: see [DEMO](http://ideone.com/9R2VtQ)

Comment: See my answer. @sleep-elite

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the address of the `char *`, to the `scanf` and `printf` function, but you are providing an element of the same. Also, you need to allocate memory to `char *a`.

```
char *a = malloc(15*sizeof(char));
while (1 == scanf("/%[^/ \t\n]", a))
     printf(">%s<\n", a);
```

Output :

```
>test<
```